# express-session deprecated undefined saveUninitialized option; provide saveUninitialized option app.js:23:9

Tags: deprecated, express-session, deprecation-warning

express-session deprecated undefined save Uninitialized option; provide save Uninitialized option app.js:23:9

express-session deprecated showing when I run the server. I changed the save uninitialized :true but its not working, give me some solution for this

I want to remove that deprecation message from my terminal

Comment: where is the code?

Comment: Try to add these two options : resave: true,  saveUninitialized: true